# Uniqueness of Integro-Differential Problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions

I shall prove the following two statements but I don't really know where to start.

> (I.D.) admits a unique solution and if $f,k$ are of class $C^p$ then y is of class $C^{p+1}$, where (I.D.) is the following Problem:
>
> **Find $y \in C^1(I_0)$ s.t. $\forall t \in I_0, y'(t)=f(t,y(t)) + \int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)ds$ and $y(t_0)=y_0$ with $y_0$ given in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ Lipschitz-continuous and $k \in C^0(I_0 \times I_0;\mathbb{R})$**. In this case $I_0=[t_0, t_0 + T] \subset \mathbb{R}, T>0.$

Because I know for ODE's that if $f$ is Lipschitz, then the problem has a global unique solution. But I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use it in this particular Integro-Differential Problem. 
And isn't it obvious that if $f,k \in C^p \Rightarrow y \in C^{p+1}$? How can I write it down mathematically correctly?

If anyone could give me a hint, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that the sum of 2 Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz too: in general, if $f$ and $g$ are Lipschitz with constants $L_1$ and $L_2$,
\begin{equation}
||f(x) + g(x) - f(y) - g(y)|| \leq ||f(x) - f(y)|| + ||g(x) - g(y)|| \leq\\
\leq L_1||x - y|| + L_2||x - y|| = (L_1 + L_2)||x - y||
\end{equation}
and $f + g$ is Lipschitz with constant $L_1 + L_2$.

I will use this to prove first the uniqueness of the solution: $f$ is Lipschitz by hypothesis and, as $k$ and $y$ are at least continuous, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you have that the integral of their product is derivable (hence it's Lipschitz because derivable implies Lipschitz).

Then, as $f(t,y(t)) + \int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)ds$ is the sum of a couple of Lipschitz functions, it is Lipschitz by the first result I showed you. This implies the uniqueness of the solution.

Now, $f,k\in\mathcal{C}^{p}\implies y\in C^{p+1}$ it's direct by bootstrap $\left(\right.$by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus if you want, writing $y(t) = y_0 + \int_{t_0}^tg(t,y(t))$ with $g(t,y(t)) = f(t,y(t)) + \int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)ds\left.\right)$. Moreover, there is an additional important result in ODE's theory which is the analogous with the initial condition $(t_0,y_0)$ of the Cauchy Problem. I give you an idea, but you will need to look at some variationals or ODE's book.

**Property**

Consider the Cauchy Problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f(t,x)\\
x(t_0) = x_0
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
where $f\in\mathcal{C}^r(\Omega)$, $r\geq 1$ and $\Omega$ is the open domain of $f$.

Then, the solution $\phi(t;t_0,x_0)$ admit derivatives until $r$ order with respect to $(t_0,x_0)$ and they are continuous with respect to $(t;t_0,x_0)$ in $\Omega$.

*Proof*

Induction on $r$:

- $r = 1$: Look at the theorem "differentiability of solutions with respect to initial conditions and parameters", you can find it in any book of ODE's.
- $r>1$

Assume it's true from $1$ to $r-1$. Then, as we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f(t,x)\in\mathcal{C}^r(\Omega)\\
x(t_0) = x_0\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0}(t;t_0,x_0) = D_xf(t,\phi(t;t_0,x_0))\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_0}(t;t_0,x_0)\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0} = Id
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
the induction hypothesis that $D_xf(t,\phi(t;t_0,x_0))\in\mathcal{C}^{r-1}(\Omega)$ implies that $\partial \phi / \partial x_0$ is differentiable $r-1$ times with respect to $(t_0,x_0)$, so $\phi$ is $r$ times differentiable with respect to $(t_0,x_0)$. This is because the las two equations form a new Cauchy Problem, etc. The same is done for $t_0$. This is called the first variational equation with respect to $x_0$ and you must look to some reference to understand what we are talking about (maybe you already know what I am talking about).

Well...that's all! I hope to help you, excuse me for the length of the answer.

Comment: Oh no, you don't have to excuse at all. :) It's always great to see the "background" behind the topic so one can develop more understanding for it. 
In this case, I totally forgot about the fundamental theorem of calculus! 
I have a question to the "Property" part: Do you mean by $D_x$ the partial derivative along x?

Comment: I mean the differential of $f$ with respect to $x$ (i.e. it's second parameter). Notice that, in general, it could be a matrix if $x\in A$ with $A$ an $n$-dimensional space, for example $\mathbb{R}^n$.